# Downloading data and appending to different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantitative-finance

I am trying to download currency pair data from Oanda using its API
I was able to create a code to download one currency from Oanda

I have 2 questions

First, from what I understand from basic python, I have to first create a list of currency pairs, then I loop through each pair in the list to download data of the pair and then I append it each individual dataframe for each pair.

```
# Input for downloading data using Oanda API
d1 = '2017-05-18'
d2 = str(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
list = ['USD_JPY','EUR_USD']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pairs': list})


gbl = globals()
for i in list:
    gbl['df_'+i] = df[df.Pairs==i]


# Downloading Data

for pair in list:

    data = oanda.get_history(instrument=list, start=d1, end=d2, granularity='D')
    df_EUR_USD= df_EUR_USD.append(pd.DataFrame(data['candles']))
```

I was able to create database for each pair in the list but I got stuck at downloading data and then appending those downloaded data to each individual dataframe.

Second question, it is about general handling in pandas. Is this the best way to handle all these data? My idea is to download those data and append them to individual dataframe and then run a loop through those lists of dataframe to do some math function and finally run another loop through the lists of dataframe again to extract the calculated data and append all of them to a new dataframe.
Is this the best approach? Or is there a better way in handling this situation.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're overwriting the built-in `list` function to your own variable `list`. Generally, it's best to avoid that.

Comment: Noted, I will change the name of my list

Comment: Also, even though it's possible, it's generally not a good idea to update the 
 `globals()` dict yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "got stuck". Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure how to proceed on with the code of loop through the list to download and to append those downloaded data to its individual dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
d1 = '2017-05-18'
#strftime return string, so cast is not necessary
d2 = pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
L = ['USD_JPY','EUR_USD']

dfs = []
for pair in L:
    #return in loop DataFrame (not tested, because no access to oanda)
    data = oanda.get_history(instrument=pair, start=d1, end=d2, granularity='D')
    #append column to list
    dfs.append(data['candles'])

#create new DataFrame with columns by L
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=L)
```

If need output as `dict`:

```
dfs = {}
for pair in L:
    data = oanda.get_history(instrument=pair, start=d1, end=d2, granularity='D')
    #add data to dict
    dfs[pair] = data['candles']

print (dfs['USD_JPY'])
```

Comment: I cannot test it with `oanda`, so if some problem let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I get an error of 'TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object'

From my previous trials, when I try to loop the downloads with 'instruments = pair' the loop only always run the 1st pair in the list. If so, do I have to do a if else statement?

Comment: Ok, what return `print (type(data))` in loop before append?

Comment: If dict, `dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(data['candles']))` should work.

Comment: Or in second solution `dfs[pair] = pd.DataFrame(data['candles'])`

Comment: print data type return dict

Comment: super, check coments above ;)

Comment: Great thanks! so if i understand correctly, we are downloading the data, then appending it to a dictionary 1st before concat the data in the dictionary into dataframe?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Output is dataframe with all data.

Comment: Will it be possible to append to individual dataframe for every currency pair downloaded? I want to do some math with the data before combining them all.

If it is not possible, then what is the best way to do some math if I have 20 pairs of data I wanna mess around with.

Comment: I think youneed second solution - it create `dict` of `DataFrames`

Comment: Thanks, your second solution works better.. But now I am stuck again..

How do I query a column in dataframe in a dictionary?

Lets say I want the time column

dfs['USD_JPY'][df['time']]

Comment: Ok, what is problem?

Comment: Need `print (dfs['USD_JPY']['col_name'])`

Comment: Or 2 steps `df = dfs['USD_JPY'])` - it return normal df and `df = df['col)name']`

Comment: Thanks, I got it working and also my looping of math function through each dataframe works. You're lifesaver! Do you have a github or something where I can follow?

Comment: No, I have no `github`. I only answering in SO if have time. But if need some nice tutorial, I like [moderna pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas). Good luck!